# Newly submitted Package in Packagist showing errors while running composer require

Tags: php, packagist

I have created a simple PHP-validation plugin.
I submit it in Packagist.Everything in Packagist seems fine but when I run my composer require command

`composer require rahulreghunath11/php-rvalidation`

Could not find package rahulreghunath11/php-rvalidation at any version for your minimum-stability (stable). Check the package spelling or your minimum-stability

showing this error.

my composer file is

```
{
    "name": "rahulreghunath11/php-rvalidation",
    "type": "library",
    "description": "PHP form validation plugin ",
    "keywords": ["validation","bootstrap validation"],
    "homepage": "https://github.com/rahulreghunath11/php-form-validation",
    "license": "MIT",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Rahul Reghunath",
            "email": "reghunath11@gmail.com",
            "role": "developer"
        }
    ]
}
```

any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error means that the `composer.json` file for your project (**NOT** your validation plugin) is missing a [`minimum-stability`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability) indicator that allows development packages, so it's defaulting to stable.

Your validation plugin is only available as `dev-master`, because you haven't tagged any [releases](https://github.com/rahulreghunath11/PHP-Form-Validation/releases) in Github yet. That means that in order for the require to work, you either have to explicitly tell it to fetch `dev-master`, or you need to set `minimum-stability` for your project to `dev`.

**Edit:**

To tell your project to use the dev-master package, specify it manually in your (project) `composer.json` file:

```
{
    "name": "example/example-app",
    "require": {
        "rahulreghunath11/php-rvalidation": "dev-master"
    }
}
```

Alternatively, if you want to be able to use `composer require` from the commandline and have it add the `dev-master` version automatically, set the `minimum-stability` to `dev` in your (project) `composer.json` file:

```
{
    "name": "example/example-app",
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "require": {
    }
}
```

Now composer will let you add packages that do not have releases:

```
composer require rahulreghunath11/php-rvalidation
```

Comment: How to add minimum stability indicator in composer.json

Comment: @RahulReghunath I've updated my answer with examples